# How to make "md-progress-circular" component from Angular material responsive?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using "md-progress-circular" component - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressCircular in my app. But it is not resizing as per the screen size. How to make it responsive? It will helpful if anyone can provide a plunker for the same.

```
<md-progress-circular md-mode="determinate" value="100" md-diameter="47"></md-progress-circular>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do it - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/wWmLmX?editors=1010)

The idea is to check for the resizing of `$window` and then change the diameter of the `md-progress-circular` accordingly.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="column">
  <div flex layout="column", layout-align="center center">
    <md-progress-circular md-diameter="{{diameter}}"></md-progress-circular>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $window, $mdMedia) {
  resizeProgress();

  angular.element($window).bind("resize", function() {
    resizeProgress();
    $scope.$apply();
  });

  function resizeProgress () {
    if ($mdMedia("gt-xs")) {
      $scope.diameter = 200;
    }
    else if ($mdMedia("xs")) {
      $scope.diameter = 100;
    }
  }
});
```